# Is it possible to schedule refresh different parts of a dataset?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powerbi, refresh, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a report on PowerBI that has many pages/tabs and each one also has alot of data being displayed. As I didn't design this, I'm going through the report to eliminate as much as I can and possibly splitting the report as alot of the data only requries refreshing once a week.

This is where my query comes in, I have information on one page that requires a refresh every two hours over a 12 hour duration, one field of data that requires a daily refresh and two more fields only require refreshing when required.

Is it possible to segment scheduled refreshes throughout a single part of the report, or does scheduled refresh only allow the entire report to be refreshed? (I.E. Sales status is hourly, Outbound status is daily, and sales summary is weekly)

I'd rather avoid having to split reports, as it is very handy to have them on one page; rather than having to open two and view them on multiple monitors.

I am just starting out on PowerBI reports, having been shown enough to get what I need done; but plan to delve further in, this being my first port of call if it is possible.

Thanks for any reponses in advance.

Brian.

Comment: Maybe connect to multiple dataflows with different refresh schedules?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's Not Possible.
PowerBI Internal working like Tabular Model.
In Import mode we can not do incremental refresh also.

So other option is you can create Reporting layer and define denormilized with calucaluated columns Reporting tables.( Sales ,summary )

and use Direct query or Refresh and Do ETL for This table.
So you can schedule ETL for specific Tables i.e.Sales  or summary.